# What is difference between pitch & lift?

Tags: lift, pitch

What is the difference between pitch and lift of an aircraft?Please kindly try to include graphics with your answers

Comment: Too elementary, no evidence of research effort, suggests no understanding of the vocabulary at all.  Plus it it essentially (probably unintended) trolling for someone to offer all kinds of inaccurate answers, like "pitch controls lift" or "lift controls climb/sink rate controls pitch", etc.

Answer (score 2):

- The **pitch axis** is one of the three axes around which an aircraft can rotate. The **pitch angle** is the angle of rotation around this axis, where zero indicates that the aircraft is level with the horizon (in pitch). You can see all three axes in the following image (from [Wikimedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Yaw_Axis_Corrected.svg)):

  [image: Pitch, Roll and Yaw]
  See also [What are the exact meanings of roll, pitch and yaw?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/66945/what-are-the-exact-meanings-of-roll-pitch-and-yaw)

  All three angles combined describe the [attitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(geometry)) of the aircraft. The term **pitch attitude** is used to describe the current pitch angle.
- The **lift** is a force acting on the aircraft. It is mostly created by the wings, but also by the horizontal stabilizer and less so by the [rest of the aircraft](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/47975/how-much-lift-comes-from-the-fuselage-on-modern-jets). You can see the typical 4 forces acting on an aircraft in the following image (from [NASA](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/forces.html)):

  [image: Forces]

  In level flight the lift is exactly equal to the weight.

The pitch angle and lift have no direct connection. Lift does indirectly depend on pitch because increasing pitch will increase the angle of attack, which will influence lift. See also [What effect does the angle of attack have on lift and drag?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/60843/what-effect-does-the-angle-of-attack-have-on-lift-and-drag)

Comment: Answer could be altered / expanded to include term "pitch attitude" as that seems a useful thing to include in an explanation of basic concepts.  E.g. "The pitch angle or pitch attitude is....".

Comment: @quietflyer OK, included a reference for attitude in general and mentioned pitch attitude in particular.